# How can I control a remote streaming VLC player with a local VLC player?

Tags: vlc-media-player, streaming, remote-control, media-player

I know VLC player can stream video and audio in several ways, and that it also has web interface along with some other ways to control it remotely. But can I make a local VLC player be able to control a remote one?

Ideally, I'd like to be able to watch all my home library media remotely via stream in MPC with full control of playback, but VLC-to-VLC would be a good start.

Answer (score 0):

[Go Here](http://www.videolan.org/doc/play-howto/en/ch04.html), and it should have a section near the bottom called **RC and RTCI**.
That is the only remote control functions in VLC. Hope that helps.